# Function Pointer - Compile time error

Tags: c++, function-pointers, pointer-to-member

I am new to function pointers and I would like your help.
I am having a method:

```
int test3(int i)
{
    return i;
}
```

Then in another method(not main) I do:

```
int (*pTest3)(int) = test3;
```

From the examples that I have read this seems ok.
However, I get a compile time error:

> testFile.cpp:277:25: error: argument of type ‘int
>   ({anonymous}::CheckingConsumer::)(int)’ does not match ‘int (*)(int)’

I do not understand what is wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Is that function a class member function? The error seems to indicate it is.... If you want to make a member function pointer it's a bit different.

Comment: This is correct syntax, there must be some other things going on. What is your compiler?
In what scoope is this code (ie. you can't use class functions here)?

Comment: There's nothing wrong with it. Look from the size of your file (at least 277 lines) that there maybe something else which is causing this  (`CheckingConsumer` ?) that you haven't included above.

Comment: It would be helpful if in your questions you could include a *complete* but minimal example showing your problem. Here we have to read between the  lines a lot to infer that `test3` is really a member of `CheckingConsumer` which makes the question harder to answer than it needs to be.

Comment: @Component10 the word "method" in the OP's question and the error message do hint strongly at what's really happening.

Comment: For future questions, please try to provide a minimal example that exhibits the problem, as your given code does compile.

Comment: @Flexo: Exactly: What is *really* happening is nothing to do with the Op's example code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your `test3` is a member function of a `struct` or a `class`.  Class member functions have a hidden `this` parameter passed into them and so cannot be used with plain function pointers.  You need to either declare the function as `static` or move it outside the `struct`/`class`, so that it no longer has a hidden `this` parameter, or use a class method pointer instead of a function pointer:

```
// static class method:
class X
{
    static int test3(int i)
    {
        ...
    }
};

// Non-class method, at global scope
int test3(int i)
{
    ...
}

// Class method pointer
class X
{
    int test3(int i)
    {
        ...
    }
};

// Create the method pointer
int (X::*pTest3) = &X::test3;
X *obj;
// Call the method pointer on an object
(obj ->* pTest3)(42);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the reply. It worked using the static keyword. However, does this affect the program at all ?

Comment: @user1491620 `static` makes it not work with an instance of your class, which significantly changes the meaning.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `test3` seems to be an instance method. Later on you define `pTest3` as function pointer, not as member function pointer.

Main difference between simple pointers and member pointers is that using the member pointer requires an instance of the object. An instance of the object tells what object should be processed and the value of the pointer tells what data field of the object should be used or what member function should be called. Value of the member pointer is conceptually equivalent to the offset from the beginning of the object to its member.

Declaring the member pointer using typedef:

```
typedef int (SomeClass::*MyMethodPtr)(int i);
MyMethodPtr ptr3 = SomeClass::test3;
```

Now using this pointer:

```
class SomeClass *pab = &ab;
int ret_value = (pab->*ptr3)(4);
```

Note that the instance of the class is used. There is other important point about the member pointers. They are implemented as structs that contain inside from 2 to 5 simple pointers and offsets depending on the compiler and other aspects like multiple inheritance, presence of vitrual base classes, etc.